# the definition of lvalue is different between C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, compilation

Look at the following code:

```
int a = 1;
(++a)++;
```

If I write this code in C souce file, and use gcc to compile it, the result is that:

> Increment operator needs lvalue

But if i write this code in c++ source file, use g++ compiler to compile it, there is no error.
. 
According to 《C++ primer 5e》, prefix increment operator returns a lvalue.

So, `++a` is a lvalue, why `(++a)++` is wrong?

Comment: Your C++ book says prefix increment operator returns a lvalue. Your C++ compiler compiles it. Your C++ book says nothing about C. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: why this code in C source file is wrong?

Comment: Why should it be right? Do you have a C book that says it's right?

Comment: Does prefix incrementation in C returns a object or lvalue?

Comment: According to the C standard it does not return an lvalue,

Comment: Could you tell me why C and C++ is so different in prefix incrementation?

Comment: C and C++ are different in operators at all, because, for example, C++ allows overloading and expressions are parsed with other parser. Actually `++a++` works only in C++... So, I think the key of this problem is in expression parsing

Comment: The C++ standard says in appendix C: "**Change:** The result of a conditional expression, an assignment expression, or a comma expression may be an lvalue. **Rationale:** C++ is an object-oriented language, placing relatively more emphasis on lvalues. For example,functions may return lvalues." The pre-increment operator is defined in terms of compound assignment in both languages so it is covered by this change too.